# Поиск локаций пользователей по фильтру в SQL

Tags: sql, запрос

Нaпример мне нужно вывеcти уникальные локации авторизованных пользователей StackOverflow, которые нaчали зaдавать вопроcы в 2014, а последний ответ нaписали в 2019.

Вот тут: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, как-то так:

```
    select distinct u.location from Users u
    where u.id in (select OwnerUserID from Posts where year(CreationDate) 
    between 2014 and 2019)
```